# Which way is the correct way to allocate memory with a property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

Which way is correct?

```
NSString *c = [[NSString alloc] init];
self.character = c;
[c release];
```

or

```
self.character = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

And why? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how your property is declared. If you used

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someString;
```

The setter will be created to retain someString, in which case the correct way is your first method. If you used:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *someString;
```

Your second method will be correct, since it will just assign the pointer and not retain anything.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you've defined your property.

If it's `copy` or `retain`, the synthesized setter (`setCharacter:` in your example) will take ownership of any objects you assign to the property. In this situation your first example is correct. The second would lead to a memory leak as you've claimed ownership of the `NSString` twice and you will (probably) only relinquish ownership once; thus the memory can never be reclaimed.

If it's `assign` on the other hand, the setter won't do anything special and your second example would be correct. The first would result in an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error if you tried to do anything with the `NSString`. I should  note that you generally only use `assign` for primitive types and delegates.

I suggest you have a read over the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) and the [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17) section of The Objective-C Programming Language guide.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your `@property` definition. Likely it's something like `(retain)` or `(copy)` for an `NSString`. In that case, assigning to self.character will increment the retain count. So the bottom:

```
self.character = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

You've set the retain count to 1 with the alloc and self.character will also retain it for a count of 2, so that'll leak. Should be

```
self.character = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or the top version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this now with iOS 5 is to use ARC.